# In numpy, how to efficiently build a mapping from each unique value to its indices, without using a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, image-segmentation

In numpy, how to efficiently build a mapping from each unique value to its indices, without using a for loop

I considered the following alternatives, but they are not efficient enough for my use case because I use large arrays.

The first alternative, requires traversing the array with `for` loop, which may be slow when considering large numpy arrays.

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
a = np.array([1, 2, 6, 4, 2, 3, 2])
inv = defaultdict(list)
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    inv[x].append(i)
```

The second alternative is non-efficient because it requires travesing the array multiple times:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 6, 4, 2, 3, 2])
inv = {}
for x in np.unique(a):
    inv[x] = np.flatnonzero(a == x)
```

EDIT: My numpy array consists of integers and the usage is for image segmentation. I was also looking for a method in skimage, but did not find any.

Comment: Given that there is no numpy structure, that can hold the result of this operation, I doubt that there is a "pure numpy" way to do this faster than with the for loop.

Comment: what do you mean by 'inverting'  a numpy array?

Comment: @pugi I clarified the question

Comment: I would question the "need" to keep the indices as sets/lists, rather than binary masks. I would also question the need to keep a dictionary, since the indices are likely contiguous and starting from 0 or 1. -- since you tagged this "segmentation", I would wonder how many different **labels** exist, as an order of magnitude at least.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, I am ok with masks rather than indices. 
labels are not contiguous in my case - but if you are aware of an efficient way that uses contiguous labels, then I can force the labels to be contiguous

Comment: well, contiguous labels meaning 1,2,3,..., or at least values from a small set of numbers (0 to 255), not practically random 64 bit integers. -- as for questions for "best" anything, I tend to avoid them because they often don't disclose the measuring stick, so there's no way to know what's "good". "traversing the array multiple times" shouldn't be considered "non-efficient". you're looking for approaches, not for hand-crafted assembly. I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```py
a = np.array((1, 2, 6, 2, 4, 7, 25, 6))
fwd = np.argsort(a)
asorted = a[fwd]
keys = np.unique(asorted)
lower = np.searchsorted(asorted, keys)
# or higher = itertools.chain(lower[1:], (len(asorted),))
higher = np.append(lower[1:], len(asorted))
inv = {key: fwd[lower_i:higher_i]
       for key, lower_i, higher_i
       in zip(keys, lower, higher)}

assert all(np.all(a[indices] == key)
           for key, indices in inv.items())
```

It runs in something like O(n log(n)). The only loop that remains is the one to build a dictionary. That step is optional, of course.

From a purely algorithmic standpoint, your first approach (defaultdict(list)) would be better since it runs in aggregated linear time but of course the python overhead may be significant.

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to check out `numba` which can speed up `numpy` code on python significantly - it supports `numpy.invert()` and `numpy.unique()` - [documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html#)

Here is a good video explaining how to use `numba` from youtube - [Make Python code 1000x Faster with Numba](https://youtu.be/x58W9A2lnQc)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer comes a bit late, but if you are ok using pandas I think you can use groupby, which should run in linear time

```
import pandas as pd
a = np.array([1, 2, 6, 4, 2, 3, 2])
df = pd.DataFrame({'values': a})
inv = df.groupby(by='values').apply(lambda group: np.array(group.index))
inv = dict(inv)
```